# HttpRequest instance add attribute dynamically in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm confused with [HttpRequest](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L43) object in Django. I know that the **AuthenticationMiddleware** will add a `user` to `request` which is an instance of HttpRequest. And the code is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L24), but what I want to show is as follow:

`request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))`

I have read the code of HttpRequest object and can not find a `user` attribute and its code don't have a `__setattr__` method. So I'm curious about why the code do not raise an AtrributeError when access to a no existing attribute.

Thanks for giving help.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about, Python will allow you to add a property/field where needed?..

Comment: if HttpRequest don't have an attribute like `user`, then you write `request.user` will raise AttributeError.@Sayse

Comment: But any time you do need to use it it will have the attribute since it is added in the auth middleware. Are you trying to use it in your own middleware *before* this middleware has been ran?

Comment: No, what I want to ask is why the code do not raise AttributeError.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpRequest` is a class which inherits from `object`. In Python attributes can be set on objects at any time.

`HttpRequest` describes a HTTP request, which in its normal state does not include any data about the user. That is why the `AuthenticationMiddleware` adds `user` to the request.

---

[`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) is the method for setting indexed items on an object.

[`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) is the method for setting an attribute on an object, and is one of the methods implemented in `object`.

---

**UPDATE**
As @sayse said that is getting.

```
>>> class Test(object):
    pass

>>> test = Test()
>>> test.user #Try to access an unset attribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    test.user #Try to access an unset attribute
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'user'
>>> test.user = 'user' #Set user attribute
>>> test.user #Try to access user
'user'
```

Comment: "In Python attributes can be set on objects at any time." I'm doubt about this words.`class Test(object):pass` , `t = Test()`, then `t.user` will raise an AttributeError.

Comment: @chyooCHENG - That is getting, not setting. (Nicely written btw, James Fenwick)

Comment: I have understood it. Thanks all!

Comment: And I want to know why it can run, is that the object achieves the `__setarr__ `method ? ＠James Fenwick